# When creating a mysql table for local places whats the best primary key?

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

What would be the best primary key for a venue in my area?

Comment: What?  With no requirements, no hint as to what columns are and no use cases, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From performance point of view - a 4 byte integer, so a surrogate key.
From some sort of a logical point of view, call it business logic - the name of the venue (natural key) assuming no 2 venues can share the same name.

Comment: -1: "assuming no 2 venues can share the same name".  With no requirements in the question, this could be a false assumption.

Comment: Hence the assuming bit because the question didn't specify it. However, you still gave it a negative review even tho the answer is correct. Isn't this supposed to be a place where people help each other instead of nitpicking? Your comment isn't really helping the topic, consider improving your comment instead of just giving it a minus without constructive input?